# Does a LINQ to Entities query eventually get translated into Entity SQL?

Tags: entity-framework

If I write a LINQ to Entities query does that get translated to a native query that the provider understands (i.e. SqlClient)?

OR

Does it get translated to Entity SQL that the Entity Framework then translates to a native query and passes to the provider?

If it gets translated to Entity SQL where I would I be able to see the Entity SQL that was generated?

If my question reveals that I'm totally screwed up in my thinking please set me straight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ to Entities does not get translated to Entity SQL. Both LINQ to Entities and Entity SQL go to what is called a "Canonical Command Tree" which the provider then converts to store-specific SQL. I've seen a couple of people who should know better claim otherwise, but [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700331.aspx) indicates the above is correct.

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/cc700331.fig04_L%28en-us%29.gif))</sub>

Comment: Ahh, thanks Craig! Now that you pointed out the CCT it makes perfect sense.